# How to setup IAM policy for AWS Lambda in VPC to resolve error "You are not authorized to perform: CreateNetworkInterface."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-vpc

[image]

I am trying to setup my Lambda to access my `Mongo server` on one of the `EC2 instances in VPC`. After selecting all the `subnets` and `security groups`, I get the following error when saving
"**You are not authorized to perform: CreateNetworkInterface.**"

I believe, I need some sort of policy setup in `AWS IAM` to allow this.

> I have "AdministratorAccess" and I am trying to add IAM role to my account.

Does anyone know what `policy/role` I need for this?

Comment: Are you trying to launch an instance? Error message is not related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nope, just trying to setup my lambda to access my VPC resources

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Gotcha!!! If the error message said "This **Lambda function** is not authorized to perform: CreateNetworkInterface" then it would have made more sense that the Lambda role needs to be modified with appropriate policy.
Fixed the problem by adding the policy to the role that the Lambda was using:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Comment: When I was creating the Lambda I got error for missing `"ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"`. I've added it and it all worked.

Answer (score 18):

It is necessary to provide the lambda with the policy actions:

```
NetworkLambdaRole:
 Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
 Properties:
   RoleName: "Network-Lambda-Role"
   AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
     Version: '2012-10-17'
     Statement:
     -
       Effect: "Allow"
       Principal:
         Service:
         - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
       Action:
       - "sts:AssumeRole"
   Policies:
   - PolicyName: "network-lambda-role-policy"
     PolicyDocument:
       Version: '2012-10-17'
       Statement:
       - Effect: "Allow"
         Action: [
           "ec2:DescribeInstances",
           "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
           "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
           "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
           "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
         ]
         Resource: "*"
```

Note: the answer from blueskin was missing the policy `ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfaces`

Answer (score 0):

There is an AWS Managed policy that includes the required permissions to allow the Lambda function to manage it's ENI interfaces.

Add this policy to the execution role of the Lambda function: `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaENIManagementAccess`

The permissions contained, as of 01/09/2024, are as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```